# C language pointer array in Struct

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, struct, malloc

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct{
    int *arr;
}example;

void Create(example var){
    var.arr = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*2);
}

int main(){
    example var1, var2;
    var1.arr = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*2);
    var1.arr[0] = 11;
    var1.arr[1] = 22;
    printf("%d %d\n",var1.arr[0],var1.arr[1]);
    Create(var2);
    var2.arr[0] = 111;
    var2.arr[1] = 222;
    printf("%d %d\n",var2.arr[0],var2.arr[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

```
OUT:
11 22
Segmentation Fault
```

My code is as above. I don't get any error when I do it manually as in var1. But if I do it inside a function as in var2, I get an error. How can I fix this. I want to do it inside the function.

EDIT:Thank you for your answers. It worked

Comment: `Create` has its argument passed by value.  Calling `Create(var2)` does not modify `var2` in any way, what's passed is a copy.  You probably want `Create` to take a pointer as an argument, or return a new `example`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function parameter

```
void Create(example var){
    var.arr = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*2);
}
```

is its local variable that is initialized by the passed argument and is not alive after exiting the function.

That is this call

```
Create(var2);
```

did not change the variable var2 declared in main.

As a result in these statements

```
var2.arr[0] = 111;
var2.arr[1] = 222;
```

there is used uninitialized pointer `arr` that has an indeterminate value that invokes undefined behavior.

You need to pass the variable by reference to the function. For example

```
void Create(example *var){
    var->arr = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*2);
}
```

and the function is called like

```
Create( &var2 );
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to pass reference of var2:
Create(&var2);

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Create() is making a *COPY* of your struct.  The original struct is unchanged.

If your program was C++, you'd want to pass a ["reference"](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/passing-arguments-by-reference/).

Here, you want to pass a pointer:

```
void Create(example * mystruct){
    mystruct->arr = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*2);
}

int main(){
    example var1, var2;
    ...
    Create(&var2);
```